# Retrieving Jenkins Container Template pre-configured Environment Variables

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm not able to get the value of the pre-configured container template environment variable in my application pipeline (`Manage Jenkins` => `Jenkins Configuration` => `Kubernetes Pod Templates` => `Container Templates` => `EnvVar`).

I'm using the latest version of Jenkins and Kubernetes Jenkins Plugin.

I tried the following and every time I end with `null`.

```
node('bunking-gibbon-jenkins-slave') {
    container('apidev-container-build'){
        stage("extraction"){
            echo("Chart Var is '${env.CHARTPATH}'")
        }
    }
}
```

OR

```
node('bunking-gibbon-jenkins-slave') {
    container('apidev-container-build'){
        stage("extraction"){
            echo CHARTPATH
        }
    }
}
```

[image: screenshot for the issue]

Comment: Isn't this supporting just specific agents for declarative pipeline only?

Answer (score 0):

from groovy, this should work: ${CHARTPATH}

Comment: Thanks, but It's not working, I'm getting the following: `groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: CHARTPATH for class: groovy.lang.Binding`